# after_request in capybara (in rspec)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, capybara

We want to validate after every request that there is no escaped HTML or XSS on the page.  In Cucumber, we have an AfterStep that does this (as long as the current page is not the same as the previous page).

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT: See https://gist.github.com/603295 for an example of an old (no longer working) version of what I'm hoping to find.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It sounds really useful.

Comment: @JoshuaMuheim sorry I didn't. I'll post an answer of the best I came up with.

Answer (score 1):

Rspec gives you these after hooks:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks

In short:

```
after(:each)
after(:all)
after(:suite)
```

Comment: That's cool, though not really what I'm looking for. See https://gist.github.com/603295 for an example of an old (no longer working) version of what I'm hoping to find.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could come up with, which was pretty close (however, it's still only after every example, not after every request):

In my spec helper, I added something like this:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.after(:each, type: :feature) do
    # this is run after each example in Capybara, and I did stuff like
    page.body.should_not match(UNESCAPED_REGEX)
  end
end
```